# I keep getting this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'url') at onClick menu-item.component

Tags: reactjs, url, routes, deprecated

this is the edited post with my code. I am trying to navigate to a any url that matches my linkUrl. I already exported MenuItem too as default

```
import { useNavigate, useMatch } from 'react-router-dom';

const MenuItem = ({ title, imageUrl, size, navigate, linkUrl, match}) => 
(
    <div 
        className={`${size} menu-item`}
        onClick={() => navigate(`${match.url}${linkUrl}`)}
    >
        <div className='background-image'
            style={{backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`}}
        />
        <div className='content'>
            <h1 className='title'>{title.toUpperCase()}</h1>
            <span className='subtitle'>SHOP NOW</span>
        </div>
    </div>
);

export function withRouter(MenuItem) {
    return (props) => {
        const navigate = useNavigate();
        const match = useMatch();
        return <MenuItem navigate={navigate} match={match} {...props} 
/>
    }
}
export default MenuItem;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code as text and not a link to the code.

Comment: import { useNavigate, useMatch } from 'react-router-dom';

const MenuItem = ({ title, imageUrl, size, navigate, linkUrl, match}) => (
    <div 
        className={`${size} menu-item`}
        onClick={() => navigate(`${match.url}${linkUrl}`)}
    >
       
);

export function withRouter(MenuItem) {
    return (props) => {
        const navigate = useNavigate();
        const match = useMatch();
        return <MenuItem navigate={navigate} match={match} {...props} />
    }
}
export default MenuItem;

Comment: Please include that in your original post and not in the comments.

Answer (score -1):

Change from `onclick` to `@click`  .

Comment: Thank you, this is the link to the code please kindly help review again. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTrQP.png

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please explain how you got to this answer.

Comment: I initially used withRouter(MenuItem) but because it was deprecated I checked online and saw how to create a custom hooks version and followed one of those posted then got the error